# Select property from max in cross apply SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join, cross-apply

I currently have this query

```
SELECT
  OC.*,
  NEW.LAST_JOB_RUN_DATE
FROM dbo.CUBES OC
CROSS APPLY (SELECT
  MAX(LAST_END_RUN_DATE) AS LAST_JOB_RUN_DATE
FROM dbo.JOBS OJ
WHERE OJ.CUBE_ID = OC.ID) NEW
```

Each `CUBE` can have multiple `JOBS`. I want this query to return me all the cubes, along with the last time the latest job was run. This works fine. Now i also want to add the `STATUS` of that job too, but i can't seem to get the query working. The query above works but doesn't return me the status associated with it, which is what i want. 
 Is there a way to change the above query to also return the `STATUS` of the job containing the `MAX(LAST_END_RUN_DATE)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  OC.*,
  NEW.LAST_JOB_RUN_DATE,
  NEW.STATUS
FROM dbo.CUBES OC
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) OJ.LAST_END_RUN_DATE AS LAST_JOB_RUN_DATE, OJ.STATUS
FROM dbo.JOBS OJ
WHERE OJ.CUBE_ID = OC.ID
ORDER BY OJ.LAST_END_RUN_DATE DESC ) NEW
```

Comment: just tried this, it only returns me the Cubes that have Jobs, if a cube has no jobs this query doesn't return it

Comment: @thegiant Try again.

Comment: it _almost_ works, i need replace `SELECT TOP(1)` by a `MAX` but this doesn't work since i need to add a `group by` because max is an aggregate function.

Comment: Why do you need a `MAX` here? Isn't the `TOP(1)` together with the `ORDER BY` give you the same thing?

Comment: it works! just had to add the `DESC` after the order by since it's `ASC` by default. thanks

Comment: Gotcha. I forgot that.